# Enable Filewriting for Javascript in firefox or Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

Is there way to enable Javascript filewriting in firefox or chrome for testing purposes?
For example with an AddON?
Or another way to store persistent data with Javascript?

Comment: Local storage api is persistent

Comment: Just googled it, thx.Good that they finnally added it. All hail HTML5!